# Calling controller action from Ember 2.0 component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Now that Ember 2.0 decided to remove the Ember.View completely I am having issues of passing actions from the view to the controller.

```
App.SomeView = Ember.Component.extend({
   didInsertElement : function(){
     var _this = this;
     window.addEventListener("message",
        function(event) {
            _this.get("controller").send("foobar", event.data);
        }, false);
  }
});

App.SomeController = Ember.Controller.extend({
   actions: {
      foobar: function(param) {
         console.log("Yey", param);
      }
   }
});
```

Because instead of Ember.View I need to use now Ember.Component. And of course then this.get("controller").send method does not work anymore. Is there some kind of workaround for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `sendAction()` in component and assign handler to it in template.

```
// some-component.js 
this.sendAction('actionName', params);

// template
{{some-component actionName="foobar"}}

// controller
actions: {
   foobar(params) {
     alert('action received');
   }
}
```

Details: http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/components/sending-actions-from-components-to-your-application/

Comment: Yup, and just to add to this, this has been around since the early 1.x days, so it's a common pattern.